# How to query XML file to display results as searched for on HTML form

Tags: php, xml, forms, simplexml, domdocument

I am trying to query my `person.xml` to display results as requested via a HTML form.

Basically, when a user searches for someone through lastname or person number, I want those results to display.

person.xml file

```
<person>
    <personN number="8">
        <personL letter="Y">
            <fullname>
                <firstname>Carl</firstname>
                <lastname>Steel</lastname>
            </fullname>
            <appearance>
                <eye>brown</eye>
            </appearance>
        </personL>  
    </personN>
  <personN number="9">
        <personL letter="Z">
            <fullname>
                <firstname>Paul</firstname>
                <lastname>Steel</lastname>
            </fullname>
            <appearance>
                <eye>blue</eye>
            </appearance>
        </personL>  
    </personN>
</person>
```

update.php file

```
<?php

$xmlDocument=new DOMDocument;
$xmlDocument->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
$xmlDocument->load("person.xml");
$personXPath = new DOMXPath($xmlDocument);



if(isset($_GET["submit"])) {

$lastN=($_GET["lastname"]);
$number=($_GET["number"]);

$lastname=$personXPath ->query("/person/personN/personL/fullname/lastname/text()='$lastN'");
foreach($lastname as $lm) {
echo $lastN->textContent;
}

$number=$personXPath ->query("/person/personN[@number='$number']");
foreach($number as $nu) {
echo $nu->textContent;
}

}


?>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <h2>Update Information</h2>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="GET">

    Person Number
    <input type="number" name="number">

    Last Name
    <input type="text" name="lastname">

    <button type="submit" name="submit">Search</button>

    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

At the moment, my code does not echo any results and I do not get any errors. I am not sure what it is doing, but it seems to be doing nothing. I want to achieve this through DOMDocument/XPath or SimpleXML (if I can). Any help would be great.

Comment: you need to search for both? number and / or lastname?

Comment: Either is fine, the user has 2 options to search through

Answer (score 1):

If you're leaning towards searching if any of those two fields are possible inputs, you can compound both queries into just one. Just use `or` on it.

```
//personN[@number='{$number}' or ./personL/fullname/lastname[contains(text(), '{$lastN}')]]
```

So in your code:

```
if (isset($_GET["submit"])) {
    $query = [];
    if (!empty($_GET['number'])) {
        $number = $_GET["number"];
        $query[] = "@number='{$number}'";
    }
    if (!empty($_GET['lastname'])) {
        $lastN = $_GET['lastname'];
        $query[] = "./personL/fullname/lastname[contains(text(), '{$lastN}')]";
    }
    $query = '//personN[' . implode(' or ', $query) . ']';

    $persons = $personXPath->query($query);
    if ($persons->length > 0) {
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            $firstname = $personXPath->evaluate('string(./personL/fullname/firstname/text())', $person);
            $lastname = $personXPath->evaluate('string(./personL/fullname/lastname/text())', $person);
            $eye_color = $personXPath->evaluate('string(./personL/appearance/eye/text())', $person);
            echo $eye_color;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works for the lastname, however for person number it does not. When I search for a person through their person number, all results show up. Also, what exactly does ```if ($persons->length > 0) {``` mean? I know what an if statement is and such but what does this statement mean?

Comment: @Miley `->length > 0` simply means that if there are persons found, i've edited it and try it again